# define java class anylogic

Tags: java, program-entry-point, anylogic

I am trying to define a java class in anylogic I need to initialize the Main class and use the agent properties in this class below is a sample of my code first I create new main object but its not initialized how I can initialize it?

```
Main main=new Main();
        Iterator<Pipe> iter=main.network.iterator();
        int i=0;
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Pipe networkc=iter.next();
        if(networkc.age<26){
            networkc.condition=1;
        }
```

Comment: Seems fine to me... Does the constructor for `Main` take any arguments?

Comment: No it doesn't the problem is the class doesn't reorganize the network agent its just empty therefore the iterator is not executed. When I contact anylogic help support they told me I need to initialize the Main class they told me I have defined the Main class but I need to initialize it they gave me the below note " the class creates new Main object. This Main is not initialized, and it is not related to the actual top-level agent. If you want to use the objects from the top-level agent, you should pass it in the class static variable or class instance." any suggestion help please

Comment: Maybe there is a Main.init() method or something like that.